# Changing elastic beanstalk's EC2 container type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-ip

I am currently running a server using Elastic beanstalk and thus automatically have been granted with an elastic IP for my auto-generated ec2 instance. Within the server I had to use ftp to fetch data from a remote server every day, and asked the other end to grant access to requests from my Elastic IP.

Now I have come to a situation where my ec2 instance has not enough memory for my services, and I wish to change its instance type to one with a bigger RAM.

Q1. If I change my instance type, will my auto-assigned Elastic IP be kept? I need confirmation because if it isn't, it will ruin my ftp cron jobs.

Q2. If I change my instance type once, will it be kept whenever Elastic Beanstalk creates a new instance for the same application? (in cases of crash, redeployment, rebuild, etc.)

Many thanks from a newbie in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q1:** An [Elastic IP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html)'s public IP address remains unchanged by a modification of the environment's Amazon EC2 instance configuration.

**Please note:** An Amazon Elastic IP address is not the same as a public IP address that has automatically been assigned to an EC2 instance. If you don't explicitly use an Elastic IP the address associated with the insstance will most likely change. If an external system relies on a static IP, you should make sure to attach a predefined Elastic IP instead of using the automatically associated one.

**Q2:** If you modify the environment's Amazon EC2 instance configuration (i.e. change the instance type), the launch configuration changes and the new configuration will be applied to subsequent deployments.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have a single-instance environment, thus it has EIP.

> Q1. If I change my instance type, will my auto-assigned Elastic IP be kept? I need confirmation because if it isn't, it will ruin my ftp cron jobs.

**Yes**. It will be kept.

> Q2. If I change my instance type once, will it be kept whenever Elastic Beanstalk creates a new instance for the same application? (in cases of crash, redeployment, rebuild, etc.)

No. By default the current instance will be **terminated and new one launched**. This happens at the **same time**. Thus, when your current instance is being terminated, new one is being launched.

To change this behavior, in `Rolling updates and deployments` have to use `Immutable` for `Configuration updates`. With `Immutable`, new instance will be launched, but the old one will be kept untouched until the new one passes its health checks. This is **much longer** update type then the first one, but **safer**.

If you worry, you can always **clone your environment** before attempting to modify it. Or perform updates on the clone and verify it it works as expected.